# How to compute intersection of N sorted sets?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std, set-intersection

The example below shows how to compute the intersection of two sets. Does the STL provide tools that allow to do this not only for 2 but for `N` sets?

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,9,3,4,5 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 9,4,2,7,4,1 };
    std::vector<int> v(v1.size() + v2.size());
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;

    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    it = std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), v.begin());

    v.resize(it - v.begin());
    std::cout << "Both sets have " << (v.size()) << " elements in common:\n";
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Intersection is associative, so to find intersection of v1, v2, v3, you can just call `std::set_intersection` twice: `result = (v1 * v2) * v3`

Answer (score 8):

> Does the STL provide tools that allow to do this not only for `2` but
> for `N` sets?

No. But you can easily make one, by providing a [recursive Variadic template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) like as follows.

The [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) part need [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) support. However, there are many examples, [how you could do it for prior to c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775706/how-to-write-a-variadic-template-recursive-function). In addition, due to recursive call the argument must be passed opposite ordered, to get the behavior you were trying.

**([See Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/abhGr7))**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  // std::set_intersection
#include <iterator>   // std::back_inserter

template<typename Container, typename... Rest>
Container NSetIntersections(
    const Container& container1, const Container& container2, Rest&&... rest) noexcept
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Rest) == 0)
    {
        Container result;
        std::set_intersection(container1.begin(), container1.end(),
            container2.begin(), container2.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        Container result;
        std::set_intersection(container1.begin(), container1.end(),
            container2.begin(), container2.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
        return NSetIntersections(result, std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // sorted vectors
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::vector<int> v3 = { 3, 4, 7, 200 };
    std::vector<int> v4 = { 4, 100, 200, 300 };
    std::vector<int> v5 = { 4, 100, 200 };
    // call the function like
    const auto res1 = NSetIntersections(v2, v1);              // 2 3 4
    const auto res2 = NSetIntersections(v3, v2, v1);          // 3 4
    const auto res3 = NSetIntersections(v4, v3, v2, v1);      // 4
    const auto res4 = NSetIntersections(v5, v4, v3, v2, v1);  // 4
    return 0;
}
```

---

In order to pass the arguments to the `NSetIntersections` function in natural way, I would suggest following helper functions manner. As a plus, it will also handle the case of passing single arguments (in case, by mistake!) to the `NSetIntersections`, and [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compatible.

**([See Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zGb5qo))**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  // std::set_intersection
#include <iterator>   // std::back_inserter

namespace helper { // helper NSetIntersections functions
    template<typename Container>
    Container NSetIntersections(const Container& container1) noexcept {
        return container1;
    }

    template<typename Container>
    Container NSetIntersections(const Container& container1, const Container& container2) noexcept
    {
        Container result;
        std::set_intersection(container1.begin(), container1.end(),
            container2.begin(), container2.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
        return result;
    }

    template<typename Container, typename... Rest>
    Container NSetIntersections(
        const Container& container1, const Container& container2, Rest&&... rest) noexcept
    {
        return helper::NSetIntersections(
            helper::NSetIntersections(container1, container2), std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    }
}

template<typename... Containers>
auto NSetIntersections(Containers&&... rest) noexcept
  -> decltype(helper::NSetIntersections(std::forward<Containers>(rest)...))
{
    return helper::NSetIntersections(std::forward<Containers>(rest)...);
}
```

Now you could call the function with args like this:

```
// sorted vectors
std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
std::vector<int> v2 = { 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9 };
std::vector<int> v3 = { 3, 4, 7, 200 };
std::vector<int> v4 = { 4, 100, 200, 300 };
std::vector<int> v5 = { 4, 100, 200 };
// call the function like
const auto res1 = NSetIntersections(v1);                 // 1 2 3 4 5 6 
const auto res2 = NSetIntersections(v1, v2);             // 2 3 4 
const auto res3 = NSetIntersections(v1, v2, v3);         // 3 4 
const auto res4 = NSetIntersections(v1, v2, v3, v4);     // 4
const auto res5 = NSetIntersections(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5); // 4
```

---

Side note: The bench mark done in quick-bench.com shows (almost) same performance (for 5 sorted containers), when we would have done N times `std::set_intersection`.

[image]

**([See Online Quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/orUANzQNPKXm6O0DJYCDjjUtjbo))**

Comment: Great approach! How can I port that to c++11?

Comment: How does the performance of this compare to an n way intersection?

Comment: @Dani *"n way intersection"* Did you mean this? https://quick-bench.com/q/kT3NFFdkFQGUMEOSO1u5vAMzlew . If yes, look like the same!

Comment: This has quite bad complexity. O(nk) where k is the number of arrays with n elements. You can do it in O(n log k).

Comment: @orlp Can you provide relavant references? I think, the answer is correct in the sence, it does the same as when we do `set_intersection` for N number of arrays. Without calling `set_intersection` N times or do we have any better/ efficient ways?

Comment: @Const A common technique is to use a min-heap, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm#Heap).

Comment: @orlp You have DVed for the wrong reason(IMHO). Please read the question. The question was not about the complexity, rather a solution for intersections of N sorted containers. And this answer provides it. If you have better thoughts, feel free to provide it as an answer!

Comment: @orlp BTW if you really had to comment about the complexity, you should have at least consider [which one of the given answers was had less effiency](https://quick-bench.com/q/uJwrrk9KNHfzUCARGY8CDf-MBQA).

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the vectors you want an intersection of in another vector and then create a function that will loop through them all and calculate the intersection of `v1` and `v2` and compare their intersection to `v3` and then compare their intersection to `v4` etc...

Here is a function that does it for you.

```
using V = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

std::vector<int> intersections(V vectors)
{
   int largest = vectors[0].size();
   for (int i = 0; i < vectors.size(); i++)
   {
      std::sort(vectors[i].begin(), vectors[i].end());
      if (vectors[i].size() > largest)
         largest = vectors[i].size();
   }

   std::vector<int> res(largest);
   std::vector<int>::iterator it;
   for (int i = 0; i < vectors.size() - 1; i++)
   {
      it = std::set_intersection(vectors[i].begin(), vectors[i].end(),
         vectors[i + 1].begin(), vectors[i + 1].end(),
         res.begin()
      );
      res.resize(it - res.begin());
      vectors[i + 1].resize(res.size());
      std::copy(res.begin(), res.end(), vectors[i + 1].begin());
   }

   return res;
}
```

Note: I have only done some very basic testing but it should work.

And this is how you call it

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,9,3,5 };
std::vector<int> v2 = { 9,4,2,7,4,1 };
std::vector<int> v3 = { 4,2,7 };
V vectors = { v1,v2, v3 };

auto res = intersections(vectors);
for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
   std::cout << res[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Your idea is good. But it is much worst performant than having N times `std::set_intersection`s for  `N+1` containers. See an [online benchmark did at quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/uJwrrk9KNHfzUCARGY8CDf-MBQA)