# Creating a base case for Variadic Template recursion with no template arguments

Tags: c++, recursion, compiler-errors, variadic-templates, constexpr

I'm trying to use recursion with variadic templates. I would like the base case to have zero template arguments. After looking through stackoverflow answers to previous questions, I have found two kinds of responses to this problem:

1. You should not specialize templates functions. Herb Sutter wrote about that here: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm
2. You use `template <typename = void>`  or `template <typename T = void>` . For example, the first answer here: [How to write a variadic template recursive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775706/how-to-write-a-variadic-template-recursive-function)

I attempted to use the solution (2) in my problem, but received errors. This is a Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename = void> // base case
int NumArguments() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename FirstArg, typename... RemainingArgs>
int NumArguments() {
    return 1 + NumArguments<RemainingArgs...>();
}
```

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << NumArguments<A>();
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation in Microsoft Visual C++20 gave the errors:

```
 error C2668: 'NumArguments': ambiguous call to overloaded function
 message : could be 'int NumArguments<A,>(void)'
message : or       'int NumArguments<A>(void)'
message : while trying to match the argument list '()'
```

What does this error message mean? How do I create a zero-argument base case for recursion with variadic templates?

**Edit:** There were requests in the comments for a more complete description of my problem. The question really is the question title, and not "how do I get my code to work?", but I have not yet gotten my code to compile, so I have decided to share it.

`NumArguments` is a stand-in for another function `ComputeSize` that takes as input `Args` and returns an `std::size_t`.

```
    template<typename = void>
    constexpr std::size_t ComputeSize() {
        return 0;
    }

    template<typename FirstArg, typename... RemainingArgs>
    constexpr std::size_t ComputeSize() {
        return FuncReturnSize<FirstArg>() + ComputeSize<RemainingArgs...>(); 
    }
```

The possible list of `Arg`s in `Args` is finite and known prior to compilation. `FuncReturnSize` is overloaded for each of these `Args`. For example, two possible "overloads"(?) are

```
template <typename T>
requires ((requires (T t) { { t.Func()} -> std::same_as<double>; }) || (requires (T t) { { t.Func() } -> std::same_as<std::vector<double>>; }))
constexpr std::size_t FuncReturnSize() {
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
requires requires (T t) { { t.Func() } -> is_std_array_concept<>; }
constexpr std::size_t FuncReturnSize() {
    return std::tuple_size_v<decltype(std::declval<T&>().Func())>;
}
```

The concept `is_std_array_concept<>` should check if the return value of `t.Func()` is some size array. I am not yet sure if it works. It is defined by

```
    template<class T>
    struct is_std_array : std::false_type {};
    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    struct is_std_array<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type {};
    template<class T>
    struct is_std_array<T const> : is_std_array<T> {};
    template<class T>
    struct is_std_array<T volatile> : is_std_array<T> {};
    template<class T>
    struct is_std_array<T volatile const> : is_std_array<T> {};

    template<typename T>
    concept is_std_array_concept = is_std_array<T>::value;
```

I want all of this computation to be done at compile-time, so I have defined

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::size_t CompilerCompute() {
    return N;
}
```

I should now be able to `ComputeSize` at compile time like so:

```
CompilerCompute<ComputeSize<Args...>()>()
```

Comment: Compiler is Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: Convert it to a class template, you can specialise those and have a zero argument base case.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yes, I believe that is what answers that talk about (1) suggest. However, (2) in my list seems to suggest that my code should work, and I don't understand the error message provided by Microsoft Visual C++ explaining why it doesn't.

Comment: Actually (2) has a clever trick that you did not implement. The base case has a type template parameter, and the general case has non-type parameters. You can have it the other way around, but you cannot have them of the same kind. This way they avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Please embrace on your intention. It's possible that you could do it with pack expansion without recursions.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, instead of comments.

Comment: Seems like the comment was deleted without adding it to the question, so I only got a peek of it. But is this what you are looking for: `return (sizeof(std::declval<T>()) + ...);`?

Comment: @cigien and Ranoiaetep sorry, I was torn between answering your question when you are so willing to help and trying to not create unnecessary work if I believe the other answers solve my problem. The question really is the title, but the full problem description may have a simpler answer worth recording here. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, it's much better now. It's not really a question of more work, or that you got an answer to your question (which is great). Posts on SO are meant to be valuable to future readers as well, and so it's good to have a clear description of your problem. Also, there may be solutions that are not apparent without seeing your use case, as you realized.

Comment: There is no need to compute the size recursively. Just use `std::size(array)` or `sizeof ... (args)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another solution (without specialization), which uses a C++20 `requires` clause to resolve the ambiguity:

```
template <typename... Args> requires (sizeof...(Args) == 0)
constexpr int NumArguments() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename FirstArg, typename... RemainingArgs>
constexpr int NumArguments() {
    return 1 + NumArguments<RemainingArgs...>();
}
```

Example:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << NumArguments<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << NumArguments() << std::endl;
    std::cout << NumArguments<float, int, double, char>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
1
0
4
```

EDIT:
My old suggestion using `concepts` was incorrect. There's a good post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68042654/16120550) on using concepts and parameter packs.

Comment: This is really cool! However, I'm confused about something. This here ```template<typename FirstArg, NonVoidArgs... RemainingArgs>``` *seems* to require at least two template arguments. There needs to be a ```FirstArg``` and then at least 1 ```RemainingArgs```. Why does the compiler call this overload(?) there is only one template argument?

Comment: @mana I thought exactly the same thing after looking at it again; removing the `NonVoidArgs` concept and replacing it with a simple `typename...` seems better (although both do compile).

Comment: I posted a question about your first solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042255/using-concepts-to-detect-empty-parameter-packs

Comment: Using a `requires` clause in the base case (rather than making a `concept`) gives the expected error with the old solution, at least on MSVC. I actually now think that's the better approach for this. There's some other weirdness; like changing `NonVoidArgs` to equal `sizeof...(Args) == 1` still 'works' for all cases, but changing it to be outright `false` or a different `sizeof...` fails. I may have misunderstood how variadiac concepts work...

Comment: Oh man, maybe don't accept it... I was clearly wrong.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it, but do you think your new solution using ```requires``` is correct? It looks to me like it works, and if it does, I think it is the best answer to this question.

Comment: It does, but the other answers explain the problem with the original question, while this was just an aside. It's up to you.

Answer (score 4):

The error message means exactly what it says, the call is ambiguous.

```
template<typename = void> // base case
constexpr int NumArguments() {
    return 0;
}
```

This is not a template function that takes 0 arguments, this is a template function that takes one argument that's defaulted (so if the argument isn't specified, it's void).  This means that `NumArguments<A>()` is a perfectly valid call to this function.

But, `NumArguments<A>()` is also a perfectly valid call to the variadic overload with an empty variadic pack (the `NumArguments<A,>()` overload listed in the error message).

What sets your case apart from the linked example is that in the linked example, the variadiac overload is templated on `int`s, not on types, so there's no ambiguity there. I've copied that implementation here:

```
template<class none = void>
constexpr int f()
{
    return 0;
}
template<int First, int... Rest>
constexpr int f()
{
    return First + f<Rest...>();
}
int main()
{
    f<1, 2, 3>();
    return 0;
}
```

Notice, the second overload of `f` is a variadic template where each template parameter must be an `int` value. Calling `f<A>()` won't match that overload if A is a type, so the ambiguity is avoided.

It's not possible to declare a zero-argument template function, so you're out of luck there. However, you can instead convert this to a class template as class templates can be partially specialized.

```
template <class ...Args> 
struct NumArguments;

template <>
struct NumArguments<> {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template <class T, class ...Args>
struct NumArguments<T, Args...> {
    static constexpr int value = 1 + NumArguments<Args...>::value;
};
```

This specific implementation could, of course, by simplified to use `sizeof...`, but the OP has indicated that their real use case is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You should guarantee the end of your variadic template without overloading the function.

A solution compiling with c++ standard 17 (in Microsoft Visual /std:c++17) is the following:

```
#include <iostream>

//Remove or comment base case!

template<typename FirstArg=void, typename... RemainingArgs>
constexpr int NumArguments() {
    if (sizeof...(RemainingArgs) == 0) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return (NumArguments<FirstArg>() + NumArguments<RemainingArgs...>());
}

class A {
public:
    A() {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << NumArguments<A>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I couldn't quite get a `is_std_array` concept to work, but in terms of your `NumArguments<T...>()`, it could be done with fold expression pretty easily:

```
template<typename ...T>
int NumArguments()
{
    return (FuncReturnSize<T>() + ...);
}
```

The fold expression here will be expanded like:

```
return (((FuncReturnSize<T1>() + FuncReturnSize<T2>()) + FuncReturnSize<T3>()) + FuncReturnSize<T4>)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hnd5rE6Ev)

Here I specialized `std::integral` and `std::floating_point` version of `FuncReturnSize()`, and any other types would just return `sizeof(T)`. And you should be able to easily specialize other types with a good concept defined.

Note I also made `FuncReturnSize()`s `consteval`.

Comment: This fails with an empty template parameter pack with ```error C7516: a unary fold expression over '+' must have a non-empty expansion```. I believe that only some operators (```&&```, ```| | ```, and ```,```) have a default value for empty parameter packs.

Comment: @mana If you are expecting 0 argument to be passed, then you can simply add `if constexpr(sizeof...(T) == 0) return 0;`