# Using concepts to detect empty parameter packs

Tags: c++, recursion, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68041842/14091616) to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68041036/14091616) I posted, Jack Harwood shared a nice solution to detect empty variadic parameter packs using concepts. The example problem is to compute the number of parameter pack arguments using recursion. I reproduce his solution below.

```
template <typename... Args>
concept NonVoidArgs = sizeof...(Args) > 0;

template <typename... Args>
concept VoidArgs = sizeof...(Args) == 0;

template <VoidArgs...>
constexpr int NumArguments() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename FirstArg, NonVoidArgs... RemainingArgs>
constexpr int NumArguments() {
    return 1 + NumArguments<RemainingArgs...>();
}
```

Example:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << NumArguments<int>() << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << NumArguments() << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << NumArguments<float, int, double, char>() << std::endl; // 4
    return 0;
}
```

I think that this is a better solution than using class templates to specialize function templates. However, I'm not sure why it works. The template function

```
template<typename FirstArg, NonVoidArgs... RemainingArgs>
constexpr int NumArguments()
```

*seems* to require at least two template arguments. There needs to be a `FirstArg` and then at least 1 `RemainingArgs`. Why does the compiler call this overload(?) when there is only one template argument? Does this behavior create any problems with this solution?

Comment: I don't see how those `concepts` and the `NumArguments` function is any different from just doing: `template<typename... Args> constexpr int NumArgs() { return sizeof...(Args); }`

Comment: @Brandon ```NumArgs``` was just an example. In my program, I have found that I want to do recursion with parameter packs. I had trouble writing the base case because of some rules about specializing template functions (I think?). The ```VoidArgs``` concept allows me to overload the function with concepts rather than specialize  (I think?). ```NumArgs``` is just an example, and this question is about the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Brandon But yes, ```NumArgs``` should do exactly what you said it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concepts themselves are correct but the problem is that the example uses them incorrectly and is itself faulty. **In the given code the concept is imposed on an argument basis instead of the entire parameter pack.**

---

Your current version

```
template<typename FirstArg, NonVoidArgs... RemainingArgs>
constexpr int NumArguments() {
  return 1 + NumArguments<RemainingArgs...>();
}
```

is actually equivalent to a `requires` clause and a fold expression

```
template<typename FirstArg, typename... RemainingArgs>
int NumArguments() requires (NonVoidArgs<RemainingArgs> && ...) {
  return 1 + NumArguments<RemainingArgs...>();
}
```

This actually means you are defining a function that must have an argument `FirstArg` and might have an additional parameter pack of arbitrary size `RemainingArgs` (including zero!). Each of these arguments - if present - is then checked independently if it fulfills the `NonVoidArgs` concept which of course is always true. This means the function basically degenerates to

```
template<typename FirstArg, typename... RemainingArgs>
int NumArguments() {
  return 1 + NumArguments<RemainingArgs...>();
}
```

That being said it is actually not even necessary for the parameter pack to be `NonVoidArgs`: [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kKYgsmB37E8aVdfE)

The correct way to impose restrictions not only on the data type of a single template argument but the entire parameter pack would actually be a `requires` clause as follows:

```
template<typename FirstArg, typename... RemainingArgs>
int NumArguments() requires NonVoidArgs<RemainingArgs...> {
  return 1 + NumArguments<RemainingArgs...>();
}
```

As expected this would not work: [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2GIDxnj2c83jT5iL) I guess the person who has written the code was just lucky it actually works as they did not enforce the concepts correctly. The basic idea behind the concept is flawed.